# How to use $lookup in mongodb to get data from this table that joins with another table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### I have 2 schemes as below:

Scheme post:

let schema = {

id: "post",

properties: {

content: { type: "string", default: '' },

author: {

type: "object",

id: { type: "object" },

avatar: { type: "string" },

firstName: { type: "string" },

lastName: { type: "string" },

status: { type: "string" }

},

hashtag: { type: 'string' },

category: {

type: "object",

id: { type: "object" },

name: { type: "string" }

},

images: {

type: "array",

items: {

type: "object",

properties: {

filePath: { type: "string" },

sort: { type: 'string' },

}

}

},

};

---

Scheme report:

let schema = {

id: "report",

properties: {

reporter: {

type: "object",

userId: { type: "object" },

firstName: { type: "string" },

lastName: { type: "string" },

status: { type: "string" }

},

to: {

type: "object",

id: { type: "object", ref: 'post' },

typeObject: { type: "string" }

},

reportType: { type: "string" }, //SPAM||FAKE ..

content: { type: "string" }

}

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDZGe.png)

How can I use $ lookup or $ populate to get data from the table post so that: post._id = report.to.id
I write like this it returns wrong as required:

findPromise = model.aggregate([

```
    { $lookup:{from:"reports",localField:"_id", foreignField:"to.id", as:"res"}},
    {
      $match: query,
    },
    { $skip: skip },
    { $limit: pageSize * 1 },

  ])
```

Please help me,
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is right, just make sure the **typeof** of both foreign and local field is same.

Comment: localField:"_id": ObjectId, 
foreignField:"to.id": 
+ to: Object,
+ id: ObjectId

I still have not returned the correct results

Comment: can you provide sample records at least one from both collection so I can work more further